# Reasoning over a triples saved in Fuseki

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, reasoning, fuseki

I have individuals saved in Fuseki and ontology related to these individuals in different file. Now I need to make some basic reasoning over individuals saved in Fuseki, for example to get only an individuals of some type. I use OWLAPI.

As a simple solution I wanted to export all individuals from Fuseki to RDF/XML file and load it to OWLAPI together with my ontology file to make reasoning. But I realized that it's not simply possible to export triples from Fuseki to RDF/XML or some other ontology format (turtle, n3 etc.) Fuseki offers only pure formats like json, xml.

So probably I'm on wrong track now. How to simply make reasoning of triples in Fuseki? Actually I'm not pushed to use Fuseki at all. I just wanted to use some triplestore, since individuals will change rapidly and I did not feel comfortable to use only RDF/XML file for storing and editing individuals.

Answer (score 2):

You should have your Fuseki instance backed by a Jena model which supports reasoning, either by using one of the Jena built-in reasoners, or hooking a compatible third party reasoner (like [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet)) up to Fuseki.

Optionally, since you mention using Fuseki is not a hard requirement, you can simply use a triple store that supports reasoning, such as [OWLIM](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim) or [Stardog](http://stardog.com).